# IF_EX_ME_CD_TRIGGER not exist in ABAP 730

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I'm trying to copy a project from an **ABAP740**'s system to another **730**, and I found that the interface class  **`IF_EX_ME_CD_TRIGGER`** doesn't exist in the 730 :

[image]

How can I fix this incompatibility ?

Answer (score 2):

It's not broken, each version brings new enhancements so this must be new in a version >7.30. The easiest thing to do it copy it from another system but honestly, I doubt if that is missing it will be the only thing missing.

So you have a couple of options,

look in the SAP marketplace and maybe just maybe it is included in a note that you can add to your system.

More then likely though I would say the development is not downward compatible if it is your own then create your own Z Interface or copy it from another system into this system.